# CURL FOLLOWLOCATION without displaying

Tags: php, curl

When I add an parameter to the CURL init function:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`

It does print the site content I'm sending a request to, the problem is that I want to manually parse the returned content (`$response = curl_exec($ch);`) but the problem is that, the site is displaying the page content and I want to keep having the site content on my `$response` variable so I could parse it, but at the same, stop it from displaying it.

Is that feasible?

The curl code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This code has no problem. I think you are echoing your response somewhere. Could you show the full code?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Nevermind you moved me in the right direction. Thank you, its working now ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag to true. From PHP.NET manual

> `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`   `TRUE`
>
> To return the transfer **as a string of the return value of** `curl_exec()` **instead of outputting it out directly**.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Got it set to `1` but it still prints the site content.

Comment: You need to set this flag before calling `curl_exec`.